# dynamic select box in wordpress template not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have a custom wordpress template and want to display a dynamic select box with values coming from database.My mysql query is running good and fetching data and whole code runs perfectly fine in core php but as I move the code to wordpress template, it is unable to show select box.Please help me where I am getting wrong.Code on wordpress template is below:

```
  <?php
  /*
  Template Name: ajaxsearch
  */


  get_header(); ?>
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="primary">
      <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

          <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

          <?php

          if (is_user_logged_in()):


            global $wpdb;
          $result = $wpdb->get_results("select hotel_id, hotel_name from hotels", OBJECT );
  //print_r($result);die('here');
          ?>
          <select name="id">
            <?php 

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              unset($id, $name);
              $id = $row['hotel_id'];
              $name = $row['hotel_name']; 
              ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
              <?php                
            }
            ?>
          </select>                                  

          <br/><br/>
          <div id="feedback"></div>
          <br/><br/>


          <?php

          endif;                                         

          ?>





        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

      </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
  </body>

  <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Screenshots:
[in local i get correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwnBI.png)

[output on wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bzI.png)

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Or better, post a screenshot of what you see in local and what in WP? Thanks.

Comment: I have attached screenshots  of both core php where I am getting correct output and of wordpress template where output is wrong.What I figured out upto now is that select box in html is the last code where after that I dont know why program terminates!

Comment: figured out correction myself yesterday.It was while loop creating the problem.I removed it to foreach and code was a charm.Don't know the reason why while loop do not work here in this wordpress template, if any thoughts will be deeply appreciated.Thanks!(topic could be closed too)

Comment: For some reason I didn't get your comments' notifications until now. Glad you solved it. You should post an actual answer explaining it and accept it to close the post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**Here is the corrected code:**

<?php
  /*
  Template Name: ajaxsearch
  */


  get_header(); ?>
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="primary">
      <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

          <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

          <?php

          if (is_user_logged_in()):


            global $wpdb;
          $result = $wpdb->get_results("select hotel_id, hotel_name from hotels", OBJECT );
  //print_r($result);die('here');
          ?>
          <select name="id">
            <?php 

          foreach ($locations as $location){
            echo "<option value='".$location->city_id."'>".$location->city_name."</option>";
        }?>
              </select>


          <br/><br/>
          <div id="feedback"></div>
          <br/><br/>


          <?php

          endif;                                         

          ?>





        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

      </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
  </body>

  <?php get_footer(); ?>
```